# UI Controls Overlapping & Fonts Issue in Windows Forms Application

Tags: c#, winforms, fonts, desktop-application

I have made a Windows Forms Application. I have a form with some controls.
The Controls overlap, and also Fonts are changed automatically, at some places the fonts go White in Buttons, TextBoxes. I am attaching a picture for more understanding.

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jg9lk.png):[image: Overlapping & Fonts Issue]

This happens in some End User's Systems, I am unable t find why this issue occurs.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thnx in Advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using system fonts and colours, your winforms application is at the mercy of the operating system's font and colour settings.

For example, if the ForeColor property of your buttons is set to ControlText (a system colour) rather than black (for example), your application will be rendered using whatever the operating system's ForeColor property is set to.

Also keep in mind that the operating system's Font Size setting will impact the layout of your forms. If the operating system's font size is set to 125% or 150% you may experience overlapping issues.

Comment: Seems useful, will try and respond. Thnx Teppic :)

Answer (score 0):

the group control seems a little small to contain the sub controls, try to make it larger enough for them.

Comment: Its quite large, this happens in some systems, in most of them it shows fine

Answer (score 0):

Try setting AutoEllipsis property to true. I believe the most right way is using layout controls combined with appropriate anchor and docking options. If set in a right way they should automatically stretch controls when needed